# How can I implement 3d graphics rendering in C with the SDL2?

Tags: c, math, 3d, sdl, sdl-2

I tried implementing a C program which draws a 3d cube using SDL2. Im sorry if it is just a stupid small mistake I'm very new to C/C++. I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/ih20l3pJoeU. The guy from the tutorial coded everything in C++ but I tried coding it in C.
But there's a problem with my code. Only parts of the Cube are drawn and it looks really weird. Here is all my code:

main.c:

```
#include "window.h"

int main() {
    window_init();
    window_startloop();

    return 0;
}
```

window.c:

```
#include "window.h"

#define false 0
#define true 1



void MultMatrixVec(vec3 *i, vec3 *o, mat4x4 *m) {
    o->x = i->x * m->m[0][0] + i->y * m->m[1][0] + i->z * m->m[2][0] + m->m[3][0];
    o->y = i->x * m->m[0][1] + i->y * m->m[1][1] + i->z * m->m[2][1] + m->m[3][1];
    o->z = i->x * m->m[0][2] + i->y * m->m[1][2] + i->z * m->m[2][2] + m->m[3][2];
    float w = i->x * m->m[0][3] + i->y * m->m[1][3] + i->z * m->m[2][3] + m->m[3][3];

    if (w != 0) {
        o->x /= w;
        o->y /= w;
        o->z /= w;
    }
}

int DrawTriangle(SDL_Renderer* p_renderer, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, Uint8 p_r, Uint8 p_g, Uint8 p_b, Uint8 p_a) {

    Uint8 r, g, b, a;

    SDL_GetRenderDrawColor(renderer, &r, &g, &b, &a);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, p_r, p_g, p_b, p_a);

    
    SDL_Point points[3] = { { x1, y1 }, { x2, y2 }, { x3, y3 } };


    int ret = SDL_RenderDrawLines(p_renderer, &points, 3);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a);

    return ret;
}

int sdl_init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) || SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
        printf("Error at initializing SDL2 Error: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int window_init() {
    if (sdl_init()) {
        return 1;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, NULL, NULL, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        
    triangle cubeTris[] = {

        // SOUTH
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        // EAST                                                      
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },

        // NORTH                                                     
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },

        // WEST                                                      
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        // TOP                                                       
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },
        { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },

        // BOTTOM                                                    
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

    };

    meshCube.tris = cubeTris;

    float fNear = 0.1f;
    float fFar = 1000.f;
    float fFov = 90;
    float fAspectRatio = (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT / (float)WINDOW_WIDTH;
    float fFovRad = 1.f / tanf(fFov / 2.f / 180.f * 3.14159f);

    matProj.m[0][0] = fAspectRatio * fFovRad;
    matProj.m[1][1] = fFovRad;
    matProj.m[2][2] = fFar / (fFar - fNear);
    matProj.m[2][3] = 1.f;
    matProj.m[3][3] = 0.f;

    isRunning = true;
    return 0;
}

void window_destroy() {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    isRunning = false;

    return;
}

void render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(meshCube.tris); i++) {
        triangle triProjected, triTranslated;

        triTranslated = meshCube.tris[i];
        triTranslated.p[0].z = meshCube.tris[i].p[0].z + 3.f;
        triTranslated.p[1].z = meshCube.tris[i].p[0].z + 3.f;
        triTranslated.p[2].z = meshCube.tris[i].p[0].z + 3.f;

        MultMatrixVec(&triTranslated.p[0], &triProjected.p[0], &matProj);
        MultMatrixVec(&triTranslated.p[1], &triProjected.p[1], &matProj);
        MultMatrixVec(&triTranslated.p[2], &triProjected.p[2], &matProj);

        triProjected.p[0].x += 1.f;
        triProjected.p[0].y += 1.f;
        triProjected.p[1].x += 1.f;
        triProjected.p[1].y += 1.f;
        triProjected.p[2].x += 1.f;
        triProjected.p[2].y += 1.f;

        triProjected.p[0].x *= 0.5f * (float) WINDOW_WIDTH;
        triProjected.p[0].y *= 0.5f * (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        triProjected.p[1].x *= 0.5f * (float)WINDOW_WIDTH;
        triProjected.p[1].y *= 0.5f * (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        triProjected.p[2].x *= 0.5f * (float)WINDOW_WIDTH;
        triProjected.p[2].y *= 0.5f * (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT;

        DrawTriangle(renderer, triProjected.p[0].x, triProjected.p[0].y, 
            triProjected.p[1].x, triProjected.p[1].y,
            triProjected.p[2].x, triProjected.p[2].y, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void window_loop() {
    render();

    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) > 0) {
        switch (e.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            window_destroy();
            break;
        }
    }

    return;
}

void window_startloop() {
    while (isRunning) {
        window_loop();
    }

    return;
}
```

window.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "3dmath.h"

#define WINDOW_TITLE "Epic 3d Game"
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 1920
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 1080

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
int isRunning;
mesh meshCube;
mat4x4 matProj;
float fTheta;

int window_init();
void window_startloop();
void window_destroy();
```

3dmath.h:

```
#pragma once

typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} vec3;

typedef struct {
    vec3 p[3];
} triangle;

typedef struct {
    triangle* tris;
} mesh;

typedef struct {
    float m[4][4];
} mat4x4;
```

First I checked if my Cube Verticies Coords are correct and they were correct. Then I deleted many parts of the code and tried to write it again while following along with the tutorial but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you've handled your global bariables in a more sensible way than written in quiestion, problems I've noticed so far:

- `DrawTriangle` passes 3 points to `SDL_RenderDrawLines`. To draw a triangle, you have to draw 3 lines, and each line consists of 2 points, so total number of points in triangle is 6:

```c
    SDL_Point points[] = {
        {x1, y1}, {x2, y2},
        {x2, y2}, {x3, y3},
        {x3, y3}, {x1, y1},
    };


    int ret = SDL_RenderDrawLines(p_renderer, &points, sizeof(points)/sizeof(points[0]));
```

- in `render`, you iterate over `sizeof(meshCube.tris)`, but sizeof of any pointer type is `sizeof(void*)` (e.g. 8 or 4 or 32bit system). You need to save number of vertices, e.g. add `int num_tris` to your mesh structure and fill it with `meshCube.num_tris = sizeof(cubeTris) / sizeof(cubeTris[0]);` in your `window_init`, where `cubeTris` is *not* a pointer but an actual array
- you set `tris` as pointer to temporary array of triangles. When you render, this array may be stomped already. You have to either allocate space for that data or set it as global/static. Declaring it as `static triangle cubeTris[] = { .... }` would suffice

As a side note, with more-or-less modern C you don't need true/false defines, as we have `#include <stdbool.h>` since C99. Also note that in C, in contrast to C++, `void foo()` is not function that takes no arguments but rather function that takes unspecified number of arguments; function thaking no arguments would be `void foo(void)`. [this should no longer be true with recent C2x, which is to be released "soon" as C23]

Comment: What do you mean by " handled your global bariables in a more sensible way"? How can  I do that? Edit: "meshCube.num_tris = sizeof(cubeTris) / sizeof(cubeTris[0]);" Is the / in that line ment as "or" or as divide?

Comment: That's a division. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is a common way to get number of elements in array, *if* it language considers it an actual array (if it isn't decayed to pointer yet)

Comment: Well you have global variables in your header file. This header is included by two `.c` files, so each defines its set of global variables. That will cause a linker error. But as it isn't part of the question I presume you handle that some other way.